# Xpath: Complex expression to include some nodes and exclude others

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Example xml:

```
<foo>
    <bar name="bar1">
    </bar>
    <bar name="bar2">
    </bar>
</foo>
<qux>
    <foo>
        <bar name="bar3">
        </bar>
    </foo>
     <bar name="bar4">
     </bar>
</qux>
```

What is the expression to select all bar elements that are children of the root foo (bar1, bar2, bar4) but not the nested foo (bar3)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is not a legal XML document.  There is more than one root element.

Comment: bar4 is not a child of the root foo.

Comment: @Michael Kay - you are right, the root foo should have covered the qux element as well.  Please see my first response to the first answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay: My interpretation is that the OP means "descendant" -- not "child"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cheeso said, the document is invalid, and it doesn't seem to jive with your question.

If this is the document you meant (where `qux` is inside the first `foo`)

```
<foo>
    <bar name="bar1">
    </bar>
    <bar name="bar2">
    </bar>
    <qux>
        <foo>
            <bar name="bar3">
            </bar>
        </foo>
        <bar name="bar4">
        </bar>
    </qux>
</foo>
```

then here are two paths

```
//bar[not(parent::foo[ancestor::foo])]
//bar[1 >= count(ancestor::foo)]
```

that will select the elements you want (tested in .NET).

Comment: Thank you for your response! You are right about the xml.  Requirements are - there can be several layers of nested foo and bar elements. Select all bar elements that are descendants of current foo and not any other foo. Thanks again!

Comment: @user897210, all right, that's more specific.  I've updated the answer with two possible solutions.  Depends on what you find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the expression to select all bar elements that are children of
>   the root foo (bar1, bar2, bar4) but not the nested foo (bar3)?

**Here is probably one of the simplest and shortest XPath expressions** that when evaluated on any well-formed XML document that has a top element `foo` and may have any level of nested `foo` elements selects exactly the `bar` elements whose only `foo` ancestor is the top element:

```
//bar[not(ancestor::foo[2])]
```

This Xpath expression selects any `bar` element in the document that has less than two `foo` ancestors. Because by definition the top element is a `foo`, this means that every `bar` has this top element `foo` as an ancestor. If it is within a nested `foo`, it has at least a second ancestor `foo` and will not be selected by the above XPath expression, because in this case `boolean(ancestor::foo[2])` is `true()`

**XSLT - based verification**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "//bar[not(ancestor::foo[2])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided XML fragment, but making it a well-formed XML document and adding a slightly more nesting/complexity, to make this interesting):

```
<foo>
    <bar name="bar1">
    </bar>
    <bar name="bar2">
    </bar>
    <qux>
        <foo>
           <baz>
             <bar name="bar3">
             </bar>
            </baz>
        </foo>
        <bar name="bar4">
        </bar>
        <qux>
            <foo>
                <bar name="bar5">
                </bar>
            </foo>
            <bar name="bar6">
            </bar>
        </qux>
    </qux>
</foo>
```

**outputs exactly the wanted elements**:

```
<bar name="bar1">

</bar>
<bar name="bar2">

</bar>
<bar name="bar4">

</bar>
<bar name="bar6">

</bar>
```

Comment: +1 for a better expression.  I knew I'd see you here sooner or later!